# Why do I see those static pictures as they are moving

Tags: perception, vision

Have a look at the following static pictures:

[image: Rollers]

[image: Rotating snakes]

There are more of them [here](http://www.ritsumei.ac.jp/~akitaoka/index-e.html).
On the same website [this PDF](http://www.psy.ritsumei.ac.jp/~akitaoka/PDrift.pdf) describes findings.However I could not find any explanation **why** this phenomenon happening.

Is it caused by eye structure itself?

Can phenomenon be explained, for example, by combination of uneven density of visual receptors from center to peripherals of the eye together with saccadic eye movement and slight delays in visual nerve signal propagation?

Or it is creation of visual cortex due to some processes in image interpretation?

I will appreciate any references to the research papers.

Comment: It is indeed. References to the research papers in the link above somehow confirm my initial guess that the phenomenon somehow related to (micro)saccadic movements of the eyes. Full picture, however, not well understood.